# MYSQL: What would be the fastest way to update the query time of a record?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

In mysql a field defined such that:

```
logtime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

It would make that when an INSERT was made, the time was recorded in this field

and if we add:

```
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This field would also be updated with the time in an UPDATE

Is there something similar for a SELECT? when a field is queried, a TIMESTAMP field is updated.

What would be the fastest way to do this?

Comment: There is no such functionality for a `SELECT`.  `SELECT` queries do not modify the database.

Comment: I know it's not a SELECT functionality.
I need to update a field when I query a record. I ask what is the fastest way to do it. I know that "ON SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" does not exist, that would be what I'm looking for, but I ask what is the way to do something similar in the fastest way (that requires less resources)